# Delete all inodes BESIDES one UNDER all instances of dir0/dir1 UNDER var/www/html, in one command

Tags: command-line

I have the dir `var/www/html` and under it there are a few website dirs (say, about 5).

All of the 5 website dirs have an internal path `dir0/dir1`.

How could I bulk delete all inodes inside this path (besides one inode named `he_IL.mo`), but in one command?

I ask about one command since I have the following block of 3 commands that works, but I would like to go minimal as much as I can with this:

```
(
find /var/www/html/*/dir0/dir1/ ! -name 'he_IL.mo' -type f -exec rm -f {} + 
find /var/www/html/*/dir0/dir1/ -type f -exec rm -d {} +
find /var/www/html/*/dir0/dir1/ -type f -exec rm -l {} + 
)
```

- If I do `*` instead of `f` I get "Should contain only a letter".
- If I do `i` instead of `f`, I get a "Unknown argument".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to use one command is removing the `-type`, from the command. Then we get:

```
find /var/www/html/*/dir0/dir1/ ! -name 'he_IL.mo' -exec rm -f {} +
```

Note that it won't will delete directories and softlinks with the name `he_IL.mo` as well, but if it's okay, use it.